# I am trying to understand how to use the REGEXP_EXTRACT function in BigQuery

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

I have a column string value:

```
SELFSERVE TICKET\STATION\TRAINCOMPANY\GBR
```

I would like to extract the part of the string before the first "\" i.e. SELFSERVE TICKET

What would be the right syntax to achieve this? If there are better functions to use I am ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that a regex is necessary here. You can just use regular string functions:

```
substr(mycol, 1, strpos(mycol, '\') - 1)
```

This gives you everything before the first `\`.

If you have strings that do not contain `\` at all, and you want to return the entire string in that case:

```
substr(concat(mycol, '\'), 1, strpos(mycol, '\') - 1)
```

Finally, if you want to get all parts at once, you can use `split()`, which returns an array of strings:

```
split(mycol, '\')
```

Comment: Thanks very much however I got the error: `Third argument in SUBSTR() cannot be negative`

Comment: Also if I wanted to split each part of the string inbetween the "/" what would be the best function to use. Outcome I would like to achieve would look like:
col 1 SELFSERVE TICKET
col 2 STATION
col 3 TRAINCOMPANY
col 4 GBR

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, I would use:

```
select split(col, '\')[ordinal(1)] as first_value
```